# How i can change column width in the barChart on MpAndroidChart library with multiDataset

Tags: mpandroidchart

I've this chart, and i populate it in two way:

```
mChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barChart);
mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);
mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
mChart.setDescription("");
mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(60);
mChart.setPinchZoom(false);

XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
xAxis.setTypeface(mTf);

YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
leftAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
leftAxis.setLabelCount(8, false);
leftAxis.setPosition(YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
leftAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f);

YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
rightAxis.setTypeface(mTf);
rightAxis.setLabelCount(8, false);
rightAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
rightAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f); 

mChart.animateY(3500);
mChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);

setData();
```

[image: Image barChart With multiDataSet]

```
// WITH ONE DATASET
public void setData(){
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
    xVals.add("");

    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(77,0));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(56,1));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(0,2));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(3,3));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(0,4));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(18,5));
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(0,6));

    BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, null);
    set1.setColor(Color.rgb(31, 144, 225));
    set1.setBarSpacePercent(50f);

    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1);

    BarData data = new BarData(xVals, dataSets);
    data.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
    data.setGroupSpace(50f);
    data.setValueTextSize(10f);
    data.setValueTypeface(mTf);

    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.invalidate();
}
```

[image: Image barChart With one dataSet]

```
//WITH MULTIDATASET
public voi setData(){
    ArrayList<String> xVals = new ArrayList<String>();
    xVals.add("");
    xVals.add("");
    xVals.add("");
    xVals.add("");
    xVals.add("");
    xVals.add("");
    xVals.add("");

    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(77,0));
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals2 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    yVals2.add(new BarEntry(56,1));
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals3 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    yVals3.add(new BarEntry(0,2));
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals4 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    yVals4.add(new BarEntry(3,3));
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals5 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    yVals5.add(new BarEntry(0,4));
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals6 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    yVals6.add(new BarEntry(18,5));
    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals7 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
    yVals7.add(new BarEntry(0,6));

    BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, null);
    set1.setColor(Color.rgb(31, 144, 225));
    set1.setBarSpacePercent(50f);
    BarDataSet set2 = new BarDataSet(yVals2, null);
    set2.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 68, 68));
    set2.setBarSpacePercent(50f);
    BarDataSet set3 = new BarDataSet(yVals3, null);
    set3.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 165, 0));
    set3.setBarSpacePercent(50f);
    BarDataSet set4 = new BarDataSet(yVals4, null);
    set4.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 136, 0));
    set4.setBarSpacePercent(50f);
    BarDataSet set5 = new BarDataSet(yVals5, null);
    set5.setColor(Color.rgb(204, 0, 0));
    set5.setBarSpacePercent(50f);
    BarDataSet set6 = new BarDataSet(yVals6, null);
    set6.setColor(Color.rgb(169, 212, 40));
    set6.setBarSpacePercent(50f);
    BarDataSet set7 = new BarDataSet(yVals7, null);
    set7.setColor(Color.rgb(102, 153, 0));
    set7.setBarSpacePercent(50f);

    ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
    dataSets.add(set1);
    dataSets.add(set2);
    dataSets.add(set3);
    dataSets.add(set4);
    dataSets.add(set5);
    dataSets.add(set6);
    dataSets.add(set7);

    BarData data = new BarData(xVals, dataSets);
    data.setValueFormatter(new LargeValueFormatter());
    data.setGroupSpace(50f);
    data.setValueTextSize(10f);
    data.setValueTypeface(mTf);

    mChart.setData(data);
    mChart.invalidate();
}
```

With the same data value, the width of bars are diferents, as shown in the pictures.

How change this.

"PS: The 'legend' is controlled by me."

Answer (score 0):

In general you can define the bar width using:
data.setBarWidth(0.75f);